# Распознавание речи из файла (офлайн). Язык программирования Python

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, kaldi

Пытаюсь освоить распознавание речи в текст. Читал о Kaldi и Vosk. Есть ли где-нибудь подробная документация?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Документация по Kaldi: http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/, https://pykaldi.github.io . По Vosk - см. ссылки внизу страницы: https://github.com/alphacep/vosk